# implementing address http in searchbar

Tags: string, swift3, xcode8, google-search, searchbar

I would need some help. Basically I have a searchbar, in this searchbar I already have to preset a link that will lead to a specific search on google. The user in the search bar will write, for example, "dog" and will be brought directly to the search results on google gif. They own the http address that leads to search results. In the text below, replace the word "lolcats" with the word entered by the user in the searchbar taking into account the spaces that are recognized by% 20

I hope I'm well explained with this poor English

example link ("lolcats" Word to be replaced with the one that inserts the user into the searchbar)

https://www.google.it/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=it&as_q=lolcats&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&tbs=itp:animated,ift:gif#imgrc=_

Answer (score 0):

try to create your url string like this:

```
var keyWord : String // which you get from user 
let part1 = "https://www.google.it/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=it&as_q="
let part2 = "&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&tbs=itp:animated,ift:gif#imgrc=_"

var encodedKeyWord = keyWord.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
var finalUrlString = part1 + "\(encodedKeyWord)" + part2
```

hope it works :S